# Host byte order and network's HostAddress6

Tags: haskell, networking, ipv6, endianness

Is there some ready-made function that converts `Word32` and `Word64` between [big/little/host-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) representations? As pointed out in the comments, this shouldn't be needed if (de)serialization is performed correctly, but could be handy in some specific situations when dealing with low-level code.

I found the following solutions, neither perfect:

1. Use [byteorder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/byteorder-1.0.4/docs/System-ByteOrder.html) to determine the current host order, and if little-endian, use [`byteSwap32`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Word.html#v:byteSwap32) on each word (or alternatively the one from [base-compat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-compat-0.9.0/docs/Data-Word-Compat.html).

   ```
   case byteOrder of
       LittleEndian -> byteSwap32
       _ -> id
   ```
2. Serialize the words with cereal's [`putWord32be`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Serialize-Put.html#v:putWord32be) and immediately read them with [`getWord32host`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Serialize-Get.html#v:getWord32host) (or alternativly `putWord32host` and read with `getWord32be`). This adds somewhat more heavy-weight dependency, but gives more flexibility for conversions to other formats.

   ```
   either (error "Unexpected error when converting ip address") id
   . runGet getWord32host . runPut . putWord32be
   ```
3. Import the native functions:

   ```
   foreign import ccall unsafe "htonl" htonl :: Word32 -> Word32
   foreign import ccall unsafe "ntohl" ntohl :: Word32 -> Word32
   ```

Is there anything better or more convenient?

Comment: I found this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpu-0.1.2/docs/System-Endian.html

Comment: Found this old Cafe thread: [(link)](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-December/052524.html) Unfortunately the thread doesn't say what happened to the functions.

Comment: It is unclear what goal you are trying to achieve. *Host* byte order is usually what you want. The byte order only starts to matter as soon as you look at individual bytes ... which you typically do when you serialize the address. Then, a serialization library such as *cereal* would be the way to go.*Only exception:* You use memcpy or pass the value to foreign functions. Then use the native functions (htonl and co).

Comment: @sapanoia You're right. Misled by the comment, II thought that `HostAddress6` stores data in its `Word32` in such a way that programs can observe the difference depending on the architecture. After examining the source code, parsing `struct in6_addr` is actually not host dependent. So for using _network_ this shouldn't be needed at all. While my question still applies, in correct scenarios where (de)serialization is done correctly, it shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are in `System.Endian` module within `cpu` package. I also needed it for my purposes.
It has many utility functions for that like:

`getSystemEndianness :: Endianness`

gets the current CPU endianess

`fromLE64 :: Word64 -> Word64`

from LE64 to platform endianess

`fromBE64 :: Word64 -> Word64`

same as above but from BE 64

`toLE64 :: Word64 -> Word64`

from CPU's Endianess to LE64

`toBE64 :: Word64 -> Word64`

from CPU's Endianess to BE64

Please note that the module provides same functions for Word32 and Word16:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpu-0.1.2/docs/System-Endian.html

Comment: Apologies, I suppose this is more elaborated.

Comment: No problem, this looks a lot better!